# SQL Server: is it better to save string of 256 or more characters as external?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

With Oracle I was always handling CHAR and VARCHAR2 of any size (from 1 to 32K) inside the table as a normal column.

I've heard some people saying that it's better to save this property as if they were external files.. instead that inside the normal table column..

Do you see any performance / other issue in using normal Varchar field for long text columns in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has facilities for actually storing data externally, called [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This keeps everything transactionally consistent.

Note the recommendation for when to use `FILESTREAM`:

> In SQL Server, BLOBs can be standard varbinary(max) data that stores the data in tables, or FILESTREAM varbinary(max) objects that store the data in the file system. The size and use of the data determines whether you should use database storage or file system storage. If the following conditions are true, you should consider using FILESTREAM:
>
> - Objects that are being stored are, on average, larger than 1 MB.
>
> ...

So, you can deduce that the general recommendation is that, for objects smaller that 1 MB (generally) use `varchar` or `varbinary` `(max)` to store them. Columns using the `(max)` data types *can* store up to 2GB of data, and the other conditions on the page linked to may be taken into consideration.

Comment: So, if I understand well.. If I will often have the textual column in the SELECT / WHERE condition and it's like 256 - 32000 chars. I should for sure inline it into the table. Is it right?

Comment: @Sam - yes, just use a `varchar(max)` column. If the actual data is small enough, SQL Server may be able to store the data "in-row" with the other columns for the same row. If the contained data gets too large, it will (behind the scenes, you don't have to do anything) start storing the data in separate pages.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle VARCHAR2 values are always stored inline the table.

For LOB objects you can specify the storage place, it can be even a different tablespace. Tiny LOB object values are still saved inline the table (by default). It can increase the performance if your query requires a Full-Table-Scan in case you do not select the LOB column.